# How to reverse a java thread to get its origin

Tags: java, byte-code

I was working on a java application which is run for the first couple of minutes & then application interface hangs. I had open the application in JMC & it shows [image: JMC Thread Details] later I create a thread dump to know more detail of the thread & it shows that most blocked count is java.lang.StringBuilder

```
Thread-1 - priority:5 - threadId:0x0000000018392800 - nativeId:0x2de0 - state:WAITING   
stackTrace:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:126)
- locked <0x00000000a1d65960> (a java.lang.StringBuilder)
Locked ownable synchronizers:
- None
```

My question is how can I be able to know for which class file the error is happening. Note: I don't have the source code of the application.
Thread dump link - [Link](https://www.sendspace.com/file/sdqv30)